# Dynamically assign structure field name with hierarchy

Tags: matlab, data-structures

I would like to be able to dynamically assign fields to a structure array, including hierarchy, in MATLAB (r2014a). I'm not sure how best to describe the problem except through the following example.

I know how to do this:

```
field_name1 = 'bar1';
field_name2 = 'bar2';
% ... etc.
foo.(field_name1) = pi;
foo.(field_name2) = exp(1);
% ... etc.
```

results in a structure variable `foo` with fields `bar1` and `bar2`.

What I would like to be able to do is this:

```
field_name1 = 'bar1';
field_name2 = 'bar2';
% ... etc.
if true_false_statement
    extra_level = '';
else
    extra_level = 'baz.';
end
foo.([extra_level field_name1]) = pi;
foo.([extra_level field_name2]) = exp(1);
% ... etc.
```

where depending on a previous condition, the fields can be stored either in the top level of the structure or else under a sub-field.

(Note that if I was doing this from scratch, I would design things differently to avoid this problem. However, I am modifying some code that is the middle step in a much larger workflow, so I have to keep the data structure consistent.)

Currently, the code looks something like this:

```
field_name1 = 'bar1';
field_name2 = 'bar2';
% ... etc.
if true_false_statement
    foo.(field_name) = pi;
    foo.(field_name) = exp(1);
    % ... etc.
else
    foo.baz.(field_name) = pi;
    foo.baz.(field_name) = exp(1);
    % ... etc.
end
```

Perhaps fine for one or two field, but there are a lot of fields, which results in a lot of copy/pasted code. I have tried making `extra_level` an empty field, and I have tried making `field_name` of the form `*.*` as above, but both options throw an error because the result is not a valid variable name.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Interesting question.  I'm looking forward to the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest manner I can think of to achieve your desired use (the middle block of code) is to use [`setfield`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setfield.html) (which is mostly a wrapper for [`subsasgn`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsasgn.html) these days) and the fact that an empty cell array expands to nothing (something I've [answered about in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28334571/3121310) and what I like to call a feature):

```
>> foo = struct();
>> extra_level = {};
>> foo = setfield(foo,extra_level{:},'bar1',1)
foo = 
    bar1: 1

>> extra_level = {'baz'};
>> foo = setfield(foo,extra_level{:},'bar2',2)
foo = 
    bar1: 1
     baz: [1x1 struct]

>> foo.baz.bar2
ans =
     2
```

Comment: That's a great trick! I can now cut out about a quarter of the lines in my function, all redundant.

Comment: I've posted a [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385908/dynamically-check-for-existence-of-structure-field-name-with-hierarchy) on how to subsequently check for the existence of the fields. Any thoughts?