# Dynamically check for existence of structure field name with hierarchy

Tags: matlab, data-structures

As a follow-up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31349895/dynamically-assign-structure-field-name-with-hierarchy) about how to *assign* fields to a structure variable with a dynamic hierarchy, I would now like to be able to *query* those fields with `isfield`. However, `isfield` will only take one argument, not a list as with `setfield`.

To summarize my problem:
I have a function that organizes data into a structure variable. Depending on certain flags, the data is saved into the substructures with a different number of levels.

For instance, the accepted answer to my previous question has me doing this to build my structure:

```
foo = struct();

% Pick one...
true_false_statement = true;
% true_false_statement = false;

if true_false_statement
    extra_level = {};
else
    extra_level = {'baz'};
end

foo = setfield(foo, extra_level{:}, 'bar1', 1);
```

which gives me `foo.bar1 = 1` if `true_false_statement` is `true`, and `foo.baz.bar1 = 1` otherwise.

Now I want to test for the existence of the field (for instance to pre-allocate an array). If I do this:

```
if ~isfield(foo, extra_levels{:}, 'bar1')
    foo = setfield(foo, extra_level{:}, 'bar1', zeros(1,100));
end
```

I get an error because `isfield` will only accept two arguments.

The best I've been able to come up with is to write a separate function with a `try`...`catch` block.

```
function tf = isfield_dyn(structure_variable, intervening_levels, field)
try
    getfield(structure_variable, intervening_levels{:}, field);
    tf = true;
catch err
    if strcmpi(err.identifier, 'MATLAB:nonExistentField')
        tf = false;
    else
        rethrow(err);
    end
end
```

As mentioned below in the comments, this is a hacky hack way to do this, and it doesn't even work all that well.

Is there a more elegant built-in way to do this, or some other more robust way to write a custom function to do this?

Comment: A few comments: 1. Please write the question in such a way that it is clear what you want without having to read other things (another question, referring to it is still good of course). 2. Using error handling to determine the flow is definitely not desirable. What about just obaining a list of fields and looping over them? 3. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve and why, if you could briefly touch that it would be easier to come up with a usefull answer.

Comment: You may also want to check the comments below my answer, as the question appears to be somewhat unclear.

Comment: Check my edits. Hopefully it's a little clearer now.

Comment: Getting there, I can already run the code, but if I run it (with either true or false) I don't get the error reproduced yet. Sorry if I appear demanding, but having a reproducible example is really important when you want nontrivial questions answered properly.

Comment: The error is simply that the solution, as you say in the first comment, requires the use of error handling to control the flow, which is undesirable. I am looking for a more robust and elegant solution.

Comment: Below thesecond codeblock it says `I get an error because isfield will only accept two arguments` yet I don't get that error. Also, you list an extra function that is never being called. --  If your second block of code would have generated an error I would say this question is ok (you get an error with 1 function, so you substitute it with an ugly alternative to make it work). However, now you still don't have a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

You might find the private utility functions [`getsubfield`](https://github.com/fieldtrip/fieldtrip/blob/master/private/getsubfield.m), [`setsubfield`](https://github.com/fieldtrip/fieldtrip/blob/master/private/setsubfield.m), [`rmsubfield`](https://github.com/fieldtrip/fieldtrip/blob/master/private/rmsubfield.m), and [`issubfield`](https://github.com/fieldtrip/fieldtrip/blob/master/private/issubfield.m) from the [FieldTrip toolbox](http://fieldtriptoolbox.org/) very handy. From the documentation of `getsubfield`:

```
% GETSUBFIELD returns a field from a structure just like the standard
% GETFIELD function, except that you can also specify nested fields
% using a '.' in the fieldname. The nesting can be arbitrary deep.
%
% Use as
%   f = getsubfield(s, 'fieldname')
% or as
%   f = getsubfield(s, 'fieldname.subfieldname')
%
% See also GETFIELD, ISSUBFIELD, SETSUBFIELD
```

Comment: Didn't try it myself yet, but perhaps good to note: The FieldTrip toolbox can be downloaded free of charge.

Comment: The `getfield`-function just returns `s = s.(t{k})` where `t` is/are the fieldname(s). The `issubfield`-function just does the same as the OP does but with the function of the toolbox. In my eyes not that helpful. Have a look at the functions by opening the source files and you'll see yourself.

Answer (score -1):

I am somewhat confused because

```
isfield(foo,  'bar1')
isfield(foo,  'baz')
```

seem to work just fine on your example struct.

Of course, if you want to test more fields, just write a loop over those fieldnames and test them one by one. That may not look vectorized, but is definitely better than abusing a `try-catch` block to guide your flow.

Comment: He wants to be able to check the existence of a field over additional levels dynamically.

Comment: @Matt you seem to understand what he wants, do you agree that the example he gives is then insufficient or am I missing even more? If the first please update it, if the latter please elaborate.

Comment: I think he misses the following line after redefining `extra_levels`: `foo = setfield(foo, extra_levels{:},'bar1',1);`. He then has a level more in the hierarchy. In your code, the field could be checked as `isfield(foo.baz,'bar1')`. But he can have more than one 'interleaving' level. So it's fully dynamical.

Comment: @Matt If you are sufficiently confident, please suggest an edit to the question. I will then look how I could update the answer

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if he left it out intentionally to just change `extra_levels`. If you take a look at the code of the function and the previous post, then you can see what he wants. He asks for a better way to write his function (that already works but surely can be improved).