# Why is a trailing comma in a cell array valid Matlab syntax?

Tags: arrays, matlab, syntax, operators, cell-array

I was surprised today to discover that

```
A = {1,2,3}
```

and

```
B = {1,2,3,}
```

are both valid syntax in MATLAB. I would have expected the second statement to yield an error. As best as I can tell, they produce identical cell arrays (`all([A{:}]==[B{:}])` returns true).

**Is  there a reason the second syntax is allowed? Is this a bug in the parser? Are `A` and `B` truly the same?**

Intriguingly, the following is *not* allowed:

```
C = {1,2,3,,,}
```

Comment: Interesting. `{1,2,4,;;;;4,5,6;;;}` also allowed

Comment: I remember exploring this quirk of the language a little bit in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28334571/3121310) but never sought a clarification from MathWorks about it. I'd chalk it up to a special case that the parser handles similar to a matrix with a `0` size in one dimension, but @LuisMendo's example raises questions as to the specifics.

Comment: @LuisMendo what really weirds me out is that it ends up a nice, tight rectangle. Seems like there should at least be some empty rows in there or something...

Comment: My working hypothesis is MATLAB allows it just to make it easier for us. For instance, if I'm copying and pasting `x(1),` into a cell array many times and then go back and change the `1`s to different #'s (a terrible idea, don't do it! Use vectors if at all possible!!!) I would have to remember to remove the last comma. By allowing this syntax, I wouldn't have to remove the last comma. I don't like that idea but its the best I've got.

Comment: @rayryeng, THIS IS THE DISASTER/DELICIOUSNESS/WEIRDNESS/MANY-OTHER-DESCRIPTIVE-WORDS THAT IS MATLAB!!!

Comment: @chessofnerd - lmao.  The nested semi-colons made me lose my $hIt.  I can't even understand what the implications of that are.

Comment: B={1,2,3,} is abuse, but {1,2,4,;;;;4,5,6;;;} is just plain evil

Comment: `{,1,2,3}` works too... Bleh. This language is weird...

Comment: But at least Matlab lets you know that it is *unneccssary* ;)

Comment: @brodroll "for there is nothing either good or bad, but [typing] makes it so." #StackShakespeare

Comment: @thewaywewalk, the one I hate is when it warns me about `str2num` being slow compared to `str2double` or something like that. IF I WANTED STR2DOUBLE I'D USE STR2DOUBLE YOU LAME EXCUSE OF AN IDE!!!

Comment: @chessofnerd - You bring much entertainment value here.  Please drop by our MATLAB chat room and further entertain us: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab-and-octave ... if you're not interested, that's ok :) Figured you may want to say hi to other SO MATLAB users who frequent here.

Comment: @rayryeng, thanks for the invite! I might try to stop by some time. Humor aside, this is a question I'm curious about. It just seems like a strange syntax.

Comment: As a headsup `[1,2,3,]` works too (presumably for the same reasons @thewaywewalk already explained).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

These are more guesses, rather than an answer.

One could check the [**Symbol reference**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/symbol-reference.html) and find that the **comma `,`** can be used as

**Command or Statement Separator**

> To enter more than one MATLAB command or statement on the same line,
>   separate each command or statement with a comma:
>
> `for k = 1:10,   sum(A(k)),   end`

In the line

```
B = {1,2,3,}
```

therefore an statement after `3` is expected, there is just `}`, which means **end of cell array**, a valid statement.

---

The **semicolon `;`** has three official usages:

**Array Row Separator**

> When used within square brackets to create a new array or concatenate
>   existing arrays, the semicolon creates a new row in the array:
>
> `A = [5, 8; 3, 4]`

**Output Suppression**

> When placed at the end of a command, the semicolon tells MATLAB not to
>   display any output from that command. In this example, MATLAB does not
>   display the resulting 100-by-100 matrix:
>
> `A = ones(100, 100);`

**Command or Statement Separator**

> Like the comma operator, you can enter more than one MATLAB command on
>   a line by separating each command with a semicolon. MATLAB suppresses
>   output for those commands terminated with a semicolon, and displays
>   the output for commands terminated with a comma.
>
> In this example, assignments to variables A and C are terminated with
>   a semicolon, and thus do not display. Because the assignment to B is
>   comma-terminated, the output of this one command is displayed:
>
> `A = 12.5;  B = 42.7,  C = 1.25;`

So in the line

```
x = {1,2,3,;5,6,7}
```

it follows the valid statement **Array Row Separator** after `3,`. Afterwards a new statement is expected, which in this case is the double **5**. Valid.

---

Now consider the case

```
x = {1,2,3,;;;;4,5,6;;;}
```

As above after `3,` follows the statement **Array Row Separator**, and the statement after that is *presumably* the [**null statement - NOP**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP) borrowed from some underlying program core written in **C**, which basically means: **do nothing**. So after `3,;` follows three times **"do nothing"**, before there comes the next statement. **Makes no sense**, as Matlab is telling you: *Extra semicolon is unnecessary.* - **but is valid.**

It also allows you pointless things like:

```
if true
    ;
end
```

---

And this is *presumably* also the reason why

```
C = {1,2,3,,,}
```

returns an error, because the comma `,` isn't a **null statement**, but after the first comma there is a statement expected.

---

The bottom line: it looks weird, but actually seems logic to me, as Matlab uses a lot of C-Code internally and considering the null statement, everything mentioned is valid syntax.

---

**What about other langages?**

Semi-colons used like `x = [1,2,3,;;;;4,5,6;;;]` in Python are invalid, even in the intended Matlab clone **numpy**, unless wrapped into this uncommon syntax `a = np.matrix('1,2,3;4,5,6')`.

```
a = np.matrix('1,2,3,;;;;4,5,6;;;')
```

would throw an error as well, as `;` is interpreted as **Array Row Separator** in any case, which makes the compiler complain about inconsitent row sizes.

However,

```
x = [1,2,3,]
```

is also valid syntax in `Python` and `IronPython`, as it is in `VBScript` and `Lua` as mentioned in [**mlepage's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32853489/2605073). What do all these languages have in common? They are all (more or less) scripting languages interpreted during runtime. It's not just Matlab. The excitement of the OP therefore remains without cause.

Comment: That actually makes perfect sense.  Thanks for the explanation. +1.

Comment: I'd be curious in throwing this The MathWorks' way and seeing if they answer!

Comment: I don't think this is correct logic. I explain why at the bottom of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51969806/7328782).

Answer (score 5):

Many languages allow one extra element separator in lists, as already mentioned. But this has nothing to do with run-time parsing. Even C allows it. It has to do with ease of use. This is a feature meant to help the user. For example, in C you can define an `enum` as follows:

```
enum E {
   a,
   b,
   c,
};
```

The comma after `c` is not required, but it is allowed. It makes it easier to add and remove elements from such a list, and it makes it easier to programatically generate such a list ([mlepage's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32853489/7328782) is correct!).

So, allowing one additional comma at the end is common across most (if not all) programming languages, it makes sense for MATLAB to support it too. The additional comma at the beginning of the list makes less sense, but I guess they support it because it doesn't hurt either.

Multiple commas in a row make no sense, this would imply there are additional elements that are unspecified.

But what is going on with the multiple semicolons then? As [Luis Mendo mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32849720/why-is-a-trailing-comma-in-a-cell-array-valid-matlab-syntax/51969806#comment53533283_32849720), `[1;;2]` is legal syntax. This is something that does deviate significantly from what other languages do.

However, it is consistent with MATLAB's use of the line break. In MATLAB, line breaks are significant. When defining an array using `[]`, line breaks indicate new rows of data:

```
M = [ 1, 2, 3,
      4, 5, 6,
      7, 8, 9,
    ];
```

is the same as

```
M = [1,2,3; 4,5,6; 7,8,9];
```

(Note how allowing the commas at the end of each row can be convenient at times.)

(Also note that I use `[]` here to concatenate, the exact same logic applies to `{}`.)

But because MATLAB wants to allow as much as possible, as long as it remains unambiguous, the above is the same as:

```
M = [ 1, 2, 3,
      4, 5, 6,


      7, 8, 9,
    ];
```

If it doesn't hurt to allow empty lines, why not allow them?

Since each newline corresponds to a semicolon, the above is identical to:

```
M = [ 1, 2, 3,;...
      4, 5, 6,;...
              ;...
              ;...
      7, 8, 9,;...
    ];
```

which is identical to

```
M = [ 1, 2, 3,; 4, 5, 6,; ; ; 7, 8, 9,; ];
```

and so MATLAB must be able to parse that, whether it makes sense or not.

---

**A rebuttal of [thewaywewalk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32850546/7328782):**

The argument is that both `,` and `;` are defined as statement separators, but somehow it is assumed that `;;;` is a valid statement whereas `,,,` is not. This is simply not true:

```
disp(0),,,disp(1)
disp(0);;;disp(1)
```

are both valid MATLAB syntax (R2017a parses both without error).

Furthermore, the answer confuses [expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_(computer_science)) and [statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_(computer_science)). `disp(0)` is a statement. The `0` in that statement is an expression. In `M=[1,2,3]`, the things separated by commas are expressions, not statements. The commas there do not work as statement separators.

In fact, in MATLAB the comma and the semicolon have multiple meanings, depending on context. The comma and semicolon at the end of a statement (including a null statement) is different from the comma and semicolon within a concatenating expression (`[1,2;3,4]`). And the comma can also separate expressions within the brackets of a function call, where the semicolon is not allowed.

Just to make this point clear:

```
1,,,4
```

is valid, whereas

```
[1,,,4]
```

is not. The commas have different functions in these two statements.

In short, the logic used in that answer is simply incorrect.

Comment: I never stated `1,,,4` outside an array would be invalid, so I don't see why my logic for the OPs case is incorrrect, because it obviously isn't.. And regarding the other points, I made clear, that I'm just guessing, so every profound correction is welcome ;)

Comment: @thewaywewalk: I guess I interpreted "because the comma `,` isn't a null statement, but after the first comma there is a statement expected" as that. Sorry if I misinterpreted your text. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's convenient to allow trailing punctuation in languages if ever the code is going to be generated from other code.

For example, Lua allows trailing commas, so it's easy to generate Lua code.

You don't have to have a special case in the generating code to omit the final comma, you can just print ITEM-THEN-COMMA for each and every item.

Comment: @Wolfie: why not? This seems the correct reasoning to me. Note that most (all?) programming languages allow this, not only for programatically generating code, but also to make it easy to edit data in source code.

Comment: @Cris I can't recall even reading this question before, comment removed, seems a fair answer! Must have been a bad day...