# Why do multiple binary operators in a row work in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, syntax, binary-operators

Why is this a valid MATLAB query?

```
3++4
```

which evaluates to `7`. Even more disturbing:

```
3+-5
```

evaluates to `-2`.

Given the following, I expected

```
3+*5
```

to evaluate to 15. Instead it throws an error.

Possible resolution related to thewaywewalk's answer to my previous question at [Why is a trailing comma in a cell array valid Matlab syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32849720/why-is-a-trailing-comma-in-a-cell-array-valid-matlab-syntax)

Comment: `3++++-++5` evaluates to -2. Guess `-` is 'stronger' than `+`? Weird...

Comment: The unary `-` negates the value, while unary `+` just returns the original value (like multiplying by -1 and 1, respectively)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+` and `-` are not only binary operators, they are also unary operators.

Documentation:

http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uplus.html
http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uminus.html

For this reasons, the first two lines are evaluated as `3+(+4)` and `3+(-5)` but the last fails because no unary multiplication exists.

Answer (score 2):

Because Matlab's [operator precedence](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operator-precedence.html) places the [unary plus](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uplus.html?refresh=true) above [binary plus](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plus.html?refresh=true).

Therefore,

```
3++4
```

is parsed to

```
plus(3,uplus(4))
```